# How can i use matplotlib on Anaconda? (Win 7 x64)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 64-bit, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda on Windows 7 64 bits but i'm unable to use any external package (numpy, matplotlib,scipy). At first when i tried to load this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I got a DLL error. Then, i downloaded and installed manually the 64 bits packages from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ but when i ran the code this message appeared: "Apparently the core died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart the core' to continue using this terminal."

I would appreciate if someone can help me with this problem because i have to do some projects and i'm wasting time. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you go into a terminal, execute python and tell me what the header looks like?

Comment: Python 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:49:46) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: Also, if i run a Python terminal instead, it shows: Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.

Comment: btw what packages did you install from the link? because it is probably unnecessary with anaconda

Comment: I installed numpy, matplotlib,pandas and scipy. I thought that i needed to install the 64 bit version of those packages.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run the installation without the mkl optimizations.

```
conda remove mkl mkl-service
conda install nomkl numpy scipy scikit-learn numexpr
```

edit:

Your problem seems to be that you installed the packages from the website and not from the anaconda channels. Clean your current environment from all packages (or create a new one) and execute:

```
conda install numpy matplotlib
```

Comment: I removed the mkl service but i can't find the 64bit version of the  nomkl packages.

Comment: Error: package missing in current win-64 channels: - nomkl

Comment: well, the only thing left which comes to my mind is to reinstall anaconda. numpy and so on are already included in the default anaconda installation